# Springboot authentication for a webhook post

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, multi-tenant

I need to authenticate a webhook post from a third party integration on my backend api server. The only thing I can define is the endpoint url they will call. It can't be dynamic once they have to register and the process takes 3 days. And we use a multi-tenant solution, so we have to authenticate with different schema on every call.

So the problem is that I have to create a filter for this webhook, so I can authenticate it through a value contained in the json of a post body.

So I defined a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and added a AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter so I can intercept the request, read the value in the json body authenticated with the appropriate credentials.

I follow this tutorial [Reading HttpServletRequest Multiple Times in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reading-httpservletrequest-multiple-times) so I could be able to read InputStream from the request without erase it.

So my question about it are two.

1: Is there a better/easy approach so I can archive this result?
2: I guess this tutorial are missing something, because I'm getting null pointer at servlet when try to read the request (again, after I have already read at the filter).

Any guess would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want help i suggest you post information about the api, your code, and a more specific problem. Voted to close, as `Is there a better/easy approach so I can archive this result` leads to opinionated answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your arbitrary decision voting to close my question. If you don't have any idea of how to help this issue I highly recommend you try to answer any other questions. Preferably one you know how to solve. Thanks again.

Comment: im not obligated to provide any feedback but will do so so you can improve your question. Before asking a question everyone should read the faq on "How to ask a good question" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask asking "is there a better way?" can lead to opinionated answers which are not allowed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions then you are asking if the tuturial is missing something because you are getting a nullpointer. We can't tell because you have not shown us your implementation. afaik you could have just missed something from the tutorial

Comment: So suggestions to improve the question are: Ask a specific problem for instance "i am getting a nullpointerexception when im trying to do x", you include your code with a stack trace that shows what is happening, and you write clear what you expected to happen. If done so, someone will probably gladly try to answer your question. If the problem is reproducible it will probably be answered even quicker. Have a nice day.

Comment: Not all questions are about runtime errors, and not working codes. Specification questions are up to been answered as well. You could help solve this problem instead voting to close it because is not your favorite type of question to answer. I suggest you save your effort to try solve questions you can, or you like the most.

Comment: Or you could just stick to your stack overflow profile description.

Comment: I'm afraid none of all your useful information gave it so far helped to solve my issue. At moment I'm acting to solve my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are we allowed to know which 3rd party service?
PayPal/Stripe for example have docs already to explain how to verify the data.

If you can add metadata/custom fields to the webhook, you could sign it for example.

As far as checking the signature/verifying it, why not do this in the @Contoller=>@Service?

Comment: Unfortunately the third party system witch i trying to integrate doesn't have a very well documented api. But I'll focus the effort on asking them to "add metadata/custom fields to the webhook" as you suggest. Perhaps is the better approach anyways. Thank you  Jcov!!